# TOP keyword in sql is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute a query for the highest salary, when I execute the query I wrote, I get the following error:

```
 SELECT TOP 3 salary FROM salary ORDER BY SALARY DESC;
```

And the error is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '3 salary FROM salary ORDER BY SALARY DESC' at line
>   1

My query is correct but I am unable to understand the problem with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalent query in `mysql`.Use `LIMIT`.`TOP` is used in `SQL Server / MS Access`.

```
SELECT salary FROM salary ORDER BY SALARY DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't have `TOP`. use `LIMIT` instead:

```
SELECT salary FROM salary ORDER BY SALARY DESC limit 3;
```